# Decide max_depth of DecisionTreeClassifier in sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, decision-tree, grid-search

When I tuning Decision Tree using GridSearchCV in skelarn, I have a question. When I decide range of `max_depth`, I think that required `max_depth` is different case by case. Because, the number of sample, or features affect to decide `max_depth`. So, Is there any appropriate criteria for decide range of `max_depth`, or it's only decided by intuition?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change the max_depth from case to case and record the performance.

This might help you to get the performance.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html

You may decide a max depth with the tests.
However, if you want to make the max_depth adapted from the tree, You can try to train another learning algorithm with enough data to find it out. (Or simply with a linear regression)

Answer (score 1):

Typically [`the recommendation`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tips-on-practical-use) is to start with `max_depth=3` and then working up from there, which the [`Decision Tree (DT)`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tree) documentation covers more in-depth.

Specifically using [`Ensemble Methods`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html) such as [`RandomForestClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) or [`DT Regression`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_tree_regression.html) is also helpful in  determining whether or not `max_depth` is set to high and/or overfitting.

Comment: For RandomForestClassifier, default value of parameter 'max_depth' is None, which means training will continue till all leaves are pure or till all leaves contain < min_samples_split.
In that case,how do I get the number of levels the training went on till it achieved its objective?

Comment: @kakoli: Try using the verbose option.

Comment: Verbose option just gives the number of trees being built.